# getTables method does not accept schema argument and returns tables from all schemas

Tags: java, sql

I want to retrieve all tables from given schema name, but getTables method does not accept any arguments (schema etc.) and it returns all tables from whole database.

I've tried to use getTables but does not work as expected from me.

```
private void countTables() throws IllegalAccessException, SQLException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Set tables = getTables();
        for (Iterator iterator = tables.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String tableName = (String) iterator.next();
            int rowCount = getRowCount(tableName);
            getWriter().write(tableName + "=[" + rowCount + "]\r\n");
        }
        getWriter().flush();
        getWriter().close();
    }
```

I want to retrieve all tables from schema test1. Now it shows results from all schemas which exists in local database.

Comment: Please post the code for method `getTables()` that returns `java.util.Set`.

Comment: This is all what I have. I am using getTables method which returns java.util.Set

Comment: I'm asking about this line of the code you posted: `Set tables = getTables();` As far as I know, there is no method `getTables()` in the JDK that takes no parameters and returns a `java.util.Set`. What class is this method in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

i.e.

```
Connection con = db.getConnection();
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();

    String tableType[] = {"TABLE"};    

   ResultSet result = metaData.getTables(null,SCHEMA_NAME,null,tableType);
 while(result.next())
    {
     String tableName = result.getString(3);
     System.out.println(tableName)
}
```

Comment: If I use ResultSet then I cannot use iterator, any idea how to easily use iterator in this case? If I change iterator to "next" method then I cannot use boolean hasNext. PS. I am a beginner in this so please be patient :)

Comment: Why do you want to use iterator?

Comment: To write all tables names one by one.

Comment: Above code does the same as the original one - it gets tables from all schemas even I put exact schema in arguments: ResultSet result = metaData.getTables(null,"testing",null,tableType);

Comment: I have added schema name as catalog parameter and now it works as expected.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that.